# 2008 R2 TLS 1.2 enabled in registry, rebooted, but not functioning

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, tls

Yes, I rebooted the server. Several times.

This actually affects both TLS 1.1 and 1.2. The only one currently working is 1.0.

I followed the instructions here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245030

I've double checked all the names and values; I've had someone else double check all the names and values.

[image: registry]

Both Qualys and IE confirm that 1.1 and 1.2 are not functioning for multiple (presumably all) HTTPS-enabled sites on the server.

Any ideas on how to further investigate this would be awesome.

Edit: More screenshots.

### [image: registry2]

[image: windows-version]

Comment: Question - Do you have the FIPS policy enabled? `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\FipsAlgorithmPolicy`

Comment: FIPS policy is disabled, but SSL v3 is also disabled separately.

Comment: I added the same in both client and server, still it didnt work after reboot the system. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To enable the system to use the protocols that will not be negotiated by default (such as TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2), change the DWORD value data of the `DisabledByDefault` value to `0x0` in the following registry keys under the Protocols key:

> SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client
>
> SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server
>
> SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client
>
> SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server

Try adding that to both TLS 1.1 and 1.2 under the `Server` key like you have it in the `Client` keys.

Comment: I'm going to try adding both Enabled (0x1) and DisabledByDefault (0x0) to both Server and Client keys. I'll reboot tonight and report back.

Comment: This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution is to use IIS Crypto.