# Windows Server 2012 R2,Foundation Edition Tls 1.1 & 1.2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, tls

Does anyone know if Windows Server Foundation edition R2 includes the latest cryptographic libraries? Specifically tls 1.2 and 1.1?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2011/10/02/support-for-ssl-tls-protocols-on-windows.aspx

This seems to indicate yes, but a Dell Small Business Rep said it does not...Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why it wouldn't support them or any documentation to prove otherwise. You may have to do some configuration to get it working, a la https://serverfault.com/a/646177/240516.

Comment: I tend to agree with you.

Comment: On Server 2012 R2 TLS 1.1 and 1.2 should be enabled by default, no need to do anything as long as you want to keep the default cipher suite order. 2012 R2 Essentials supports them, I also don't see why Foundation shouldn't but I don't have one to verify that.

Comment: Thank you Peter. I don't see anything that says that foundation edition does not.... other than that rep - but he seemed very sure of it so I thought I would double check.